# Simple question on exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Apologies for this question but I want to solve for $t$ in the following, and the answer is that we cannot solve for $t$ but I do not know why:

$904.281e^{-0.085t} = 0$. Why can we not solve for $t$ ? Why can't we take log of the products on the left and log of 0 on the right?

Thank you

Comment: $\log (0)$ is not defined...

Comment: consider the graph of $f(t) = e^{-0.085t}$. It is clear that it never intercepts the t-axis. Hence there is no solution for $f(t) = 0$

Comment: in less rigorous language, "t equals infinity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm is a function from $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ to $\Bbb{R}$, and as such inherently not defined at zero. Thus taking $log(f(x_0))$ has no meaning when $f(x_0)=0$.